# Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^{15}(1.6^n-12n+1)$. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic, problem-solving

> Find the value of
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{15}(1.6^n-12n+1)$$
> giving your answer correct to one decimal place.

[[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRod8.png)]

I separated the summation into two parts:

The summation of $1.6^n$ and the summation of $1-12n$.

I then put the equations into the summation formula:

I got $$\frac{1-1.6^{16}}{1-1.6} + \frac{16}{2}(1+(15)(-12))$$

This gave me an answer of $1640.8$, but the given answer is $1648.8$.

> Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The factor of $\frac{16}2$ should apply only to $15(-12)$; the $1$ term should be multiplied by $16$, not by $8$.

Comment: Why is that though, @BrianM.Scott?

Comment: "Why is that though"  because you are either *averaging* the first  and last terms, $a+d*0$ and $a+d*15$ and multiplying by that number of terms to get $16(\frac {a+d*0 + a+d*15}2)=16(\frac {2a + 15d}2=16(a + \frac {15d}2)$.  Or you are *adding* the first and last terms and multiplying by half the number of terms to get $\frac {16}2(a+d*0 + a+d*15)=\frac {16}2(2a + 15d)$.  The $a$ term is *constant* and it occurs $16$ times so it is $16a$.  It's only the $n*d$ that varies and that you need to average and multiply by half.

Answer (score 0):

The $1$ shouldn't have its contribution halved, so the correct answer is $8$ more than you said.

Answer (score 0):

How/why did you figure $\sum_{n=0}^{15}(1-12n)=\frac {16}2 (1+15(-12))$?

I don't like memorizing formulas so the only one I memorize is $\sum_{n=0|1}^M n = \frac {M(M+1)}2$.  And that way $\sum_{n=0}^{15}(1-12n) = \sum_{n=0}^{15}1 - 12\sum_{n=0}^{15}n= 16 - 12(\frac {15\cdot 16}2)$.

But some people memorize (where I would derive)  $\sum_{n=0}^M (a+bn) = \sum_{n=a}^{a+M}bn = b(M+1)\frac {(a + 0\cdot b)+(a+Mn)}2= \frac {M+1}2b(2a+Mn)=\frac {16}2(2+15(-12))$.

So I guess you mangled the formula. We "average" the changes in the value so the $-12*0$ to $-12*15$ are added and divided in half.  But the constant offset of $1$ stays canstant and there are $16$ of the so ..... we *don't* divide those by half.

======

Okay, a lot of text have a formula for the sum arithemetic series given as

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (a+dk) = $(half the number of terms)$\times$(the first term plus the last term$=$

$\frac n2([a + 0*d] + [a + (n-1)*d])=$

$\frac n2(\color{red} 2a + (n-1)*d)$.

You are not taking the $\color{red}2$ into account.  The $a$ term contributes to the first term *AND* to the last term.  So you must take $a$ into account twice.

....

But.... don't just memorize formulas.  *Always* reason them out.

$\sum_{k=0}^{15} (1-12n) = $(number of terms)$\times$(average number of terms) and as this is an arithmetic progression $=$

$16 \frac {\text{first term} + \text{last term}}2=$

$8(1 + [1+(-12)15])=$

$8 (2 -12*15)$.

Comment: I used the formula for the sum of an arithmetic series - n/2(a+(n-1)d)...was that incorrectly used here?

Comment: Where's you get that formula? Is doesn't seem to me to be correct.  If $a$ is the first term ($1$) and $n$ is the number of terms, and $d$ is the increment of terms, The formula should be #of r terms$\times$(average of terms)$=n\frac{\text{first term}+\text{last term}}2=n\frac{a + (a +(n-1)d)}2=\frac n2(2a +(n-1)d)= a +\frac {n(n-1)d}2$.  You should have divided the $a$ by $2$.  There are a full $n$ of them,, not $\frac n2$ of them.  And it's not that the $n$ should be halfed.  It's that the $0*d ..... (n-1)*d$ should be averaged.

Comment: Every site I've found gives the sum of an arithmetic series as $\sum_{k=0}^n(a + dk) =\frac n2(\color{red}2a + (n-1) d)$ so, yes, you were incorrectly using it.

Comment: My mistake! I wasn't thinking straight. Thanks @fleablood for explaining this to my thick brain!! Have a great day :)